# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/stream/buffer/XMLStreamBuffer"

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, wildfly

I created jax-ws service and it worked succesfly with tomcat then i install wildfly 8 for another project and it does not work and ı got "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/stream/buffer/XMLStreamBuffer" error message when i run it.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I think yo have a bunch of JAX-WS jars in your application that might conflicts with those provided by the server.

Comment: I deleted these jars but I got the same error

Comment: delete everything with JAXB, stax or xml-apis in it's name